# Question about GPT-2 causal masking for downstream tuning

Tags: transformer, gpt, huggingface

I'm currently finetuning a pre-trained GPT-2 model for image captioning. Using a ViT for image encoding, the output embeddings are then fed into the GPT-2 model (from HuggingFace) as  `inputs_embeds`, concatenated with a `<|caption|>` token and the caption. The input is like this:

<|CLS|>[img_features]...[img_features]<|caption|>[caption_embeds]...[caption_embeds]<|endoftext|>

My question is, is the `input_embeds` part masked by a casual mask during the forward process? If so, can this part be separately masked (no mask) aside from the caption inputs?

Thanks for any advice/comments/discussion!